# How to display same type of data from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT and XML.

I have got below XML.

```
<documentCountryInformation>
        <countryCode>US</countryCode>
        <countryName>United States</countryName>
        <sufficientDocumentation>Conditional</sufficientDocumentation>
        <sectionInformation>
          <sectionName>Health</sectionName>
          <documentParagraph paragraphId="23628">
            <paragraphType>Requirement</paragraphType>
            <paragraphText>
              <p>
                Vaccination for
                <strong>yellow fever</strong>
                Persons without valid yellow fever certification, if required, are subject to quarantine for a period up to 6 days.
              </p>
            </paragraphText>
          </documentParagraph>            
        </sectionInformation>
</documentCountryInformation>
<documentCountryInformation>
        <countryCode>IN</countryCode>
        <countryName>India</countryName>
        <sufficientDocumentation>Conditional</sufficientDocumentation>
        <sectionInformation>
          <sectionName>Health</sectionName>
          <documentParagraph paragraphId="23648">
            <paragraphType>Requirement</paragraphType>
            <paragraphText>
              <p>
                Vaccination for
                <strong>Dengue fever</strong>
                Persons without valid yellow fever certification, if required, are subject to quarantine for a period up to 3 days.
              </p>
            </paragraphText>
          </documentParagraph>            
        </sectionInformation>
</documentCountryInformation>
```

Above is the part of full xml and you can see there are **two** records of same type, now I have got the `<countryName>` in parameters of XSLT in above example my **countryName** parameter will contain this type of data **"United States,India"**, Now I want to split the parameter data and further it will check the XML having same country name and display the data according, I mean there will be loop on **country name** and below is desired HTML.

```
<div class="resultsContainer" id="divTransit">
        <h3>Transit - United States (US)</h3>                            
        <p>
        Vaccination for
        <strong>yellow fever</strong>
        Persons without valid yellow fever certification, if required, are subject to quarantine for a period up to 6 days.
        </p>

        <h3>Transit - India (IN)</h3>                            
        <p>
        Vaccination for
        <strong>Dengue fever</strong>
        Persons without valid yellow fever certification, if required, are subject to quarantine for a period up to 3 days.
        </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. This output seems very straight forward to do with a XSLT template match, Why do you need a "loop"?

Comment: its was my thought yes your are right we can use template match, I thought we may need as I have split the parameter values also. Please suggest

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to split the parameter data
>   and further it will check the XML
>   having same country name and display
>   the data according, I mean there will
>   be loop on country name and below is
>   desired HTML.

**There is no need to "split" the parameter value, nor for a "loop" of any kind**.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="pCountryName" select="'United States,India'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <div class="resultsContainer" id="divTransit">
     <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "*[contains(concat(',',$pCountryName,','),
                  concat(',',countryName,',')
                  )
        ]
      "/>
   </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="documentCountryInformation">
  <h3>
    <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat('Transit - ',
             countryName,
             ' (',
             countryCode,
             ')'
             )
     "/>
  </h3>
  <xsl:copy-of select="*/*/paragraphText/node()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (wrapped in a top element to become wellformed):

```
<t>
    <documentCountryInformation>
        <countryCode>US</countryCode>
        <countryName>United States</countryName>
        <sufficientDocumentation>Conditional</sufficientDocumentation>
        <sectionInformation>
            <sectionName>Health</sectionName>
            <documentParagraph paragraphId="23628">
                <paragraphType>Requirement</paragraphType>
                <paragraphText>
                    <p>
                Vaccination for
                        <strong>yellow fever</strong>
                Persons without valid yellow fever certification, if required, are subject to quarantine for a period up to 6 days.
                    </p>
                </paragraphText>
            </documentParagraph>
        </sectionInformation>
    </documentCountryInformation>
    <documentCountryInformation>
        <countryCode>IN</countryCode>
        <countryName>India</countryName>
        <sufficientDocumentation>Conditional</sufficientDocumentation>
        <sectionInformation>
            <sectionName>Health</sectionName>
            <documentParagraph paragraphId="23648">
                <paragraphType>Requirement</paragraphType>
                <paragraphText>
                    <p>
                Vaccination for
                        <strong>Dengue fever</strong>
                Persons without valid yellow fever certification, if required, are subject to quarantine for a period up to 3 days.
                    </p>
                </paragraphText>
            </documentParagraph>
        </sectionInformation>
    </documentCountryInformation>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<div class="resultsContainer" id="divTransit">
   <h3>Transit - United States (US)</h3>

   <p>
                Vaccination for
                        <strong>yellow fever</strong>
                Persons without valid yellow fever certification, if required, are subject to quarantine for a period up to 6 days.
                    </p>

   <h3>Transit - India (IN)</h3>

   <p>
                Vaccination for
                        <strong>Dengue fever</strong>
                Persons without valid yellow fever certification, if required, are subject to quarantine for a period up to 3 days.
                    </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a template

```
<xsl:template match="documentCountryInformation[contains($countryName, countryName)]">
```

Comment: Note this assumes that no country name can contain any other country name. If you want more robust matching, you can append delimiters, as @Dimitre's answer shows.